# SequelizeEagerLoadingError in associated models

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm getting an issue when I add include in my query, and I can't figure out why. I have two models: **User** and **Transaction**

**User**

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING
      }, {});
      User.associate = function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Transaction, {
          foreignKey: 'senderId',
          as: 'sender',
        }),
        User.hasMany(models.Transaction, {
          foreignKey: 'receiverId',
          as: 'receiver',
        })
      };
      return User;
    };
```

**Transaction**

```
  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Transaction = sequelize.define('Transaction', {
      amount: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {});
    Transaction.associate = function(models) {
      Transaction.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'senderId'
      }),
      Transaction.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'receiverId'
      })
    };
    return Transaction;
  };
```

Both senderId and receiverId are available in db after migration.

Attempted query:

```
  Transaction
    .findAll({
      where: { senderId: req.params.userId },
      include: [{
        model: User,
        as: 'sender',
      },{
        model: User,
        as: 'receiver',
      }],
    })
```

Expected Result:

```
  {
    "transactions": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "amount": 300,
        "sender": {
          "id": 2,
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "email": "jdoe+123@gmail.com",
        },
        "receiver": {
          "id": 3,
          "firstName": "John1",
          "lastName": "Doe1",
          "email": "jdoe+132@gmail.com",
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "amount": 900,
        "sender": {
          "id": 2,
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "email": "jdoe+123@gmail.com",
        },
        "receiver": {
          "id": 3,
          "firstName": "John1",
          "lastName": "Doe1",
          "email": "jdoe+132@gmail.com",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I'm getting the error: **SequelizeEagerLoadingError**

Is their something wrong with association or query?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an alias to one or both of those associations, currently they are overwriting eachother.
Something like:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Transaction = sequelize.define('Transaction', {
    amount: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Transaction.associate = function(models) {
    Transaction.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: 'sender',
      foreignKey: 'senderId'
    }),
    Transaction.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: 'receiver',
      foreignKey: 'receiverId'
    })
  };
  return Transaction;
};
```